# Card layout and adding keylistener to a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, keylistener, cardlayout

I set card layout manager for my main `JPanel` in the main window.

```
public  class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    JPanel contentPanel;

    public MainFrame(){}

    contentPanel = new JPanel();
    contentPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    contentPanel.removeAll();
    contentPanel.add(new ContentPanel1());
    contentPanel.repaint();
    contentPanel.revalidate()

}
```

Now I have a button in the `ContentPanel1` class. When it is clicked, it goes for a new `Panel(WorkPlace panel)`. I want to have a key listener for this panel (`WorkPlace`) but it doesn't work.

```
public class WorkPlace extends JPanel implements key{
    public WorkPlace(){
       this.setFocusable(true);
       this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed " + e.getKeyChar());
    }        
}
```

After clicking the button in `ContentPanel1`, `WorkPlace` panel comes up in `MainFrame` but its keylistener dosen't work. What's wrong here?
Note that I only bring here some of the code in these classes and each class is in separate files.

Comment: In `WorkPlace`, what does `panel` reference?  You should be using Key Bindings anyway, but it's hard to judge based on the available information

Comment: when you add a Card, you should specify a name for it., ie use the two argument form of add.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I found key listener works after minimizing Frame, what should i do?